# How to sort an array of integers based on its binary representation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, integer

Problem title: Binary Sort Ascending:

I have a task which consists of creating a function in JavaScript which orders an array that receives a list of unordered integers. The function must return an ordered array of integers according to the following criteria:

1. The greater number of ones in the binary representation of the integer, the closer to the index 0 the element should be.
2. In case two or more numbers have the same number of ones in their binary representation, the decimal number
   of lesser value will be closer to the beginning.

Example:

For the entry: [1, 15, 5, 7, 3]

The return should be: [15, 7, 3, 5, 1]

Explanation:

Decimal = Binary

- 1 = 1
- 15 = 1111
- 5 = 101
- 7 = 111
- 3 = 11

The decimal number whose binary representation contains plus ones is 15 (1111 in binary), so it will go first in the array (index = 0). Then go on the 7, with three (111) ones in its binary representation.

Then there are 2 numbers whose binary representation contains
the same number of ones, these decimals are 5 (101) and 3 (11), both with 2 ones. In this case, it will go first (closer to index = 0) the 3, because it's decimal representation is smaller (3 < 5).

Solution:

Finally, I have found a way to solve this task:

```
const binaryOnes = integerArr => {

  let binaryArray = integerArr.map(num => num.toString(2))

  binaryArray.sort((a, b) => {

    let regEx = /1/g
    let A = a.match(regEx).length
    let B = b.match(regEx).length

    if (A < B) return 1
    else if (A > B) return -1
    else {
      let binaryToIntegerA = parseInt(A, 2)
      let binaryToIntegerB = parseInt(B, 2)

      if (binaryToIntegerA < binaryToIntegerB) return -1
      else return 1
    }
    
  })

  return binaryArray.map(num => parseInt(num, 2))

}

binaryOnes([1,15,5,7,3]) // [ 15, 7, 3, 5, 1 ]
```

Please if anyone finds a better way to solve it, I will appreciate.

Also some feedback of this post (is my first question on StackOverflow)

Thanks!

Comment: Please try something yourself first then let us know if and where you have trouble

Comment: one method: 1.change it to binary representation (probably string) 2.sort 3.change back.

Comment: You are going to need to get this closer to code for SO. - WWC

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is my first question in StackOverflow. Finally, I got the solution and posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a number into binary (string type) with something like

```
var binary = 134.toString(2);
```

Then, implement the comparison function between two numbers with

```
function binaryCompare(a, b) {
    a = a.binary;
    b = b.binary;
    //...
}
```

After that, just call

```
[1,2,34,342]
.map( a => ({value:a, binary: a.toString(2))
.sort(binaryCompare)
.map( v => v.value );
```

As I don't understand your goal, I cannot implement the sort function.
Hope it helps

Comment: No need to implement everything ... If the question looks like a challenge or homework, it is actually [better if the answers leave some parts up to the OP.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) (so good job :))